# Horizantal children divs- fixed width and percentage width- percentage width too wide

Tags: html, size, width, percentage, children

So, I have this code
http://pastebin.com/W3ggtgZB as css, and the body looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/2tkmhnfW

What I am trying to do  is create a div with two children divs, one of which has a fixed width, and the other one I want to fill the rest of the blank space. I'm eventually going to want a div going across the top of this side div, too, but, that comes later. My issue is, the child div sub1 expands to be 100% of its parent width, which is an issue, because then it overlaps out of the parent div and keeps going. I tried things like floating left, using block and inline, I tried setting the width to auto (which makes it disappear for some reason) - but nothing seems to really work. It looks okay, at first, but when you zoom in, sub1 kinda follows its own rules. Can someone help me fix it so that sub1 will just fill in the rest of the space left in the main div?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

http://dabblet.com/gist/6069015

Only need to specify the side column's floating and the rest will take place as you want, adapting the screen size as well. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: you are almost literally my hero. thanks, I dont know why i was overthinking this lol. probably because it was 430am

Comment: No problem! And please can you accept it as an answer? I would like to build up my reputation :)